# type object 'Questions' has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django

Im new in django , When im learning django from documentation .i tried to make api using serializers and Function Based views .the this shows type object 'Questions' has no attribute 'objects

**models.py**

```
class Questions:
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(default='inactive', max_length=30)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from demoapp.models import Questions


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Questions
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
            'description',
            'created_by',

        )
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from demoapp.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('poll', demoapp),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from demoapp.models import Questions
from demoapp.serializers import QuestionSerializer
from django.http import JsonResponse

def demoapp(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        queryset=Questions.objects.all()
        serializer=QuestionSerializer(snippets)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data,safe=False)
```

Comment: You did not inherit from `Model`.

Comment: Furthermore the name of a model is typically singular, so `Question`, not `Questions`.

Answer (score 4):

you should inherit your model class from django `models.Model`:

```
from django.db import models

class Questions(models.Model):
```

and after this changes you should do and apply migration, read the docs: [migrations commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#the-commands)(thank the @Willem Van Onsem for his comment).

Comment: it can be true, please edit your question with full stack of error.

Comment: @DineshKc: is it the *same* error? I have the idea that you probably should *migrate* your app.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes sir,

Comment: Thnks its Working properly ,

Comment: @DineshKc don't forget to accept the answer, for other who will search solution in the same trouble.

Comment: Thnks sir ,I will do

Answer (score 0):

In your models You didn't end bracket:

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE
```

It should look like this:

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And you probably did not import User

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

And you can try to make migrations

Comment: i think it is typo in the question not in code, the error should be syntax for your case.

Comment: sir i havent typed in the end bracked.

Comment: Yes Sir,Thnks A lot Above BOth Comments helped me

Comment: Thanks for nice words